# Using Intent data and finish in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-intent

I'm creating an application such that the user is in an Activity, and opens up an AlertDialog.

Inside the alertDialog is a button that opens a second activity, waits for the result and fills a textfield in the alertDialog.

Well, at least it is supposed to.

Heres a snippit to better illustrate the problem:

```
private String mFillAddrField = "";
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data == null) {
            ...
        } else {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras(); //DATA retrieved from second activity successfully
            mFillAddrField = b.getString("address");
        }
    }
}

...
public void displayAddScreen() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Create a new Grocery Store");
    alert.setMessage("Create a new store by filling out the form below.");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newstore_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.nsd_root));

    final EditText nameField = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.nsd_et_name);
    final EditText addrField = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.nsd_et_address);
    final Button addrSelect = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.nsd_b_address);

    alert.setView(layout);

    addrSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Open MAPS API return me an address
            //Save address to text field
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroceryMapActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
            addrField.setText(mFillAddrField); //OFFENDING CODE HERE
        }
    });
```

My problem is that the call to addrField.setText comes before the activity is completed (probably before its started too!), how can I wait here until the activity returns a result, then continue the rest of the code (setting the text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move addrField.setText() to your onActivityResult() method

(You can't stop and wait in the UI thread the way you seem to want to)

I've changed the supplied code to make addrField a class member and move setting it to match what you want to do:

```
private String mFillAddrField = "";
EditText addrField;
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data == null) {
            ...
        } else {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras(); //DATA retrieved from second activity successfully
            mFillAddrField = b.getString("address");
            addrField.setText(mFillAddrField);
        }
    }
}

...
public void displayAddScreen() {
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Create a new Grocery Store");
alert.setMessage("Create a new store by filling out the form below.");

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newstore_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.nsd_root));

final EditText nameField = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.nsd_et_name);
addrField = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.nsd_et_address);

final Button addrSelect = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.nsd_b_address);

alert.setView(layout);

addrSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Open MAPS API return me an address
        //Save address to text field
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroceryMapActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i,0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm I don't think that is possible in my instance. The 'addrField' only exists in the context of the alertdialog, not the entire activity..

Comment: So what I did do, that pseudo-worked, was to inflate the layout and set the text of addrField in  'onActivityResult()' method.. The problem? It only works after I click the button again and back out...

Comment: You can put 'EditText addrField = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.nsd_et_address);' in onActivityResult() as well (or make addrField a member of the class)

Comment: @esteve -- I would make the layout a class member, and only inflate it once

Comment: I followed your suggestion of making layout and addrfield class members, still no dice.

Comment: @esteve -- Check the updated code I posted; make addrField a class member and move setting it to the onActivityResult; no other changes

Comment: Thank you for your edits. This is basically the answer, in addition to Leffelmania's helpful post. What is needed is to change my implementation such that I can easily close and re-open the alert dialog after setting the value I retrieved from the second activity. Thanks to you and Leffelmania for your help and quick replies!!

Answer (score 1):

When you build the `AlertDialog`, call `addrField.setText(mFillAddrField)` right after you initialize it. The first time you build the dialog, `addrField` will be empty. When `onActivityResult()` finishes, the address will be in `mFillAddrField` and when you rebuild the dialog you'll be able to set `addrField` to the address.

Comment: Okay now i think were getting closer. onActivityResult() finishes and the address is set in addrField AFTER the dialog has been rebuilt. How can I close the dialog from the onClick method in the dialog?

Comment: Well typically when using an `AlertDialog.Builder` one would use the provided `setPositiveButton()` method (and other utility methods), and that click will automatically dismiss the dialog. If that won't work for you, I'd suggest keeping a reference to your dialog (storing `alert.create()` in a member variable) so that you can call `show()` and `dismiss()` on it as needed. Then I'd have a `refresh()` function to update its fields before I show it.